# Simple Raspberry Pi 2 GPIO does't work

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a simple push button script using RPi.GPIO on my Raspberry Pi 2 with the following code.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:

  input_state=GPIO.input(25)
  if input_state==False:
    print("Open")
    time.sleep(0.1)

  GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, the above code doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the script give error? or does it say "Open" all the time?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your question to show exactly what you're doing, and re-formatted the code so that it doesn't have superfluous indentation. However, you should edit your question even further. A good question will have a question (check, we have that), concrete code (check, we have that too), output of the program (still missing) and expected output (still missing). "Doesn't work" is too vague; describe what the program does and what you expected it to do.

Comment: You have to use `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end (outside the while loop). Otherwise it will clean the pin configuration and will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from having the `GPIO.cleanup()` inside the while loop.

You have to move it outside the loop.

Otherwise if you execute it at each iteration, it will delete the pin configuration and your scrip will not work properly.

Also you might be interested in the `GPIO.wait_for_edge` that will only trigger when an edge is detected (falling or rising).

Example code:

```
while True:
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(25, GPIO.RISING)
    print('Button 1 Pressed')
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(25, GPIO.FALLING)
    print('Button 1 Released')
GPIO.cleanup()
```